# Facebook Login Native opens in browser instead of facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic2

I'm struggling to have a facebook login that opens in the facebook native app instead of the browser.
I'm aware of the fact that this kind of scenario could only be tested on a real device, and because of that I'm carrying out all of my testing on an iPhone 6 device running the latest iOS version.

I found out that the problem could be located in the call

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform: Platform) {
    Facebook.browserInit(this.FB_APP_ID, "v2.8");
}
```

at first I thought it was due to the fact that the system was trying to reference to a plugin that was not yet available, so I wrapped everything into a

```
this.platform.ready()
   .then(() => {
       console.log('view did load');
       Facebook.browserInit(this.FB_APP_ID, "v2.8");
   });
```

but it didn't change a thing.
So I keep getting the same error which is

```
 Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pluginInstance[methodName].apply')
```

Nevertheless if I comment the Facebook.browserInit call everything works (in the browser window).

the bottom line of all this, is the fact that even though the first thing that my app does is to pop a a browser window, in that window (if you are not already logged in via safari ), facebook gives you the choice to proceed to log in via web or to open the app and finish the log in process there. Anyway this is a really convoluted process, when it could be so easy and straightforward.

FWIW here's the rest of the code

```
doFbLogin() {
  let permissions = new Array();
  // let nav = this.navCtrl;
  //the permissions your facebook app needs from the user
  permissions = ["public_profile", "email"];

  let _this = this;
  Facebook.login(permissions)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("response: ", response);
      let userId = response.authResponse.userID;
      let params = new Array();

      //Getting name and gender properties
      Facebook.api("/me?fields=name,gender,email", params)
        .then(function (user) {
          console.log('graph call succedeed ', user);
          user.picture = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large";
          //now we have the users info, let's save it in the NativeStorage
          _this.user = {
            name: user.name,
            gender: user.gender,
            picture: user.picture,
            email: user.email
          }
          _this.loggedIn = true;
          NativeStorage.setItem('user', _this.user).then(function () {
            //nav.push(UserPage);
            console.log('user logged!');
          }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
        })
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: have you installed the plugin for browser or specific platform? And can you please pin-point what exact problem you are facing?

Comment: unfortunately I did it already :-(